# I have difficulty understanding why the condition is necessary in this linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field of cardinality not equal to 2 and we consider the linear functionals on $\mathbb{K}^{3}$, $f_{1}(X)=x+y-z$, $f_{2}(X)=x-y+z$, $f_{3}(X)=x+y-z$. The point of the problem is to show that $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$ and $f_{3}$ form a basis of $\left(\mathbb{K}^{3}\right)^{*}$ and to find its dual basis. I have solved the problem and got $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ and $\left(0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ as the dual basis. But I have difficulty understanding why the condition $\mathbb{K}$ be a field of cardinality not equal to 2 necessary in this problem.

Comment: You probably mean the characteristic, not the cardinality. In fields with characteristic 2, 2=0, so you can't divide by 2, as you did in order to find your dual basis.

Comment: Yes, I meant the characteristic. Sorry, there was a typo error.